# PHP array elements not entering correctly in bootstrap

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

These are the image links which I want to insert into bootstrap carousel:

```
function display_slides() {
    $count = 10;
    $iter = 0;
    $image_links = ['https://i.imgur.com/9wHVhck.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/SpBfUZi.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ZqoEU9o.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/n2JY9jj.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/yD5I5WH.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/JKNnuSE.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/YwAmPYu.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/T7NBjJm.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ujJ3g1k.jpg'];
    while ($iter < $count) {
        if ($iter == 0) {
            $output .='
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/dCS4tQk.jpg" alt="Background Image">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <p>Sample text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';
        } else {
// print_r($image_links[$iter]);
            $output .='
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100 src=' . $image_links[$iter] . ' alt="Background Image">
         <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <p>Sample text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';
        }
        $iter ++;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I want to enter the links which are in $image_links into src of img tag. The first slide (in which the link is hard coded), works and the rest of the slides do not work.
[Link to full php file](https://pastebin.com/D55bVaUy)
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "do not work" what do you mean by this? the links are not there? the carousel doesn't work?

Comment: 1. The maximum index of your array is 8, your `$iter`'s value can go up to 9. 2. you need to quote the src value: `src="' . $image_links[$iter] . '"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to close the class attribute.
Your code

```
<img class="d-block w-100 src=' . $image_links[$iter] . ' alt="Background Image">
```

Working code

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="'.$image_links[$iter].'" alt="Background Image">
```

Answer (score 2):

brother. you are missing the closing quotation mark in an img tag `class="d-block w-100`

this code will work for you perfectly..

```
$image_links = ['https://i.imgur.com/9wHVhck.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/SpBfUZi.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ZqoEU9o.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/n2JY9jj.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/yD5I5WH.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/JKNnuSE.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/YwAmPYu.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/T7NBjJm.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ujJ3g1k.jpg'];

    for ($i=0; $i <count($image_links) ; $i++) { 
        // echo $image_links[$i];exit;
        echo '<div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="'.$image_links[$i].'" alt="Background Image">
                     <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Header</h2>
                        <p>Sample text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned the code up a little bit and used a foreach loop instead of using an iterator.  I highly suggest using a foreach loop whenever you want to access an array as it is typically much easier to read.  As other have suggested, there was also a quotation mark missing on your class attribute that has also been fixed below.

Using variables like a count and an iterator are unnecessary and can become difficult to read once you get into multi-dimensional arrays.

```
 function display_slides() {
    $image_links = ['https://i.imgur.com/9wHVhck.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/SpBfUZi.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ZqoEU9o.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/n2JY9jj.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/yD5I5WH.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/JKNnuSE.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/YwAmPYu.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/T7NBjJm.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/ujJ3g1k.jpg'];
    $output .='
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/dCS4tQk.jpg" alt="Background Image">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Sample text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
     foreach ($image_links as $image ) {
         $output .='
         <div class="carousel-item">
         <img class="d-block w-100 src='.$image.'" alt="Background Image">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h2>Header</h2>
         <p>Sample text</p>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
        ';
        }
    }
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely look into foreach more.

Answer (score 0):

I because there is some HTML syntax error, You are not given quotes (") for src. it sould be like below

```
} else {
      $output .='
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img style="border:1px solid #0f0" class="d-block w-100 src="'.$image_links[$iter].'" alt="Background Image"> // note the quotes added on src=""
```

Hope its clear.

Happy coding.